# Ember - if lastItem in each

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to show a piece of markup under the very last item in an each in ember -- I tried something like @last - but it came back with an error

```
<ul>
  {{#each people as |person index|}}
    <li>Hello, {{person.name}}! You're number {{index}} in line</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ember's `{{each}}` template helper does not provide an easy way to do so.

As you might figured out, you could use `{{unless index}}` to conditionally render stuff on the first object. This is working since index starts at zero and `0` is considered to be falsely.

You could combine [`ember-truth-helpers`](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) and [`ember-math-helpers`](https://github.com/shipshapecode/ember-math-helpers) to achieve something comparable for last element. Both are well maintained ember addons that provide a full set of template helpers.

Ember-truth-helpers provides a `eq` helper that adds support for equal comparison in templates. Ember-math-helpers provides a `sub` helper to subtract a value from another in a template. Combining both of them we could build a condition that will be true only for the last element:

```
{{#each items as |item index|}}
  <li>
    {{item}}
    {{#unless index}}(first){{/unless}}
    {{#if (eq index (sub items.length 1))}}(last){{/if}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

You find an ember twiddle demonstrating the approach here: https://ember-twiddle.com/6ea05a2e9c884bd772eefabc91173d08?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

It's even simpler if the array is an [`Ember.NativeArray`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Ember.NativeArray). `NativeArray` of ember provides a [`lastObject` property](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.9/classes/Ember.NativeArray/properties/lastObject?anchor=lastObject), which points to the last item in the array. You could use that one for equal comparison directly as pointed out by @Gaurav in a comment: `{{#if (eq item items.lastObject)}}(last){{/if}}` But be aware that this may give wrong results if the array has duplicated elements.

Comment: I had to add the ember maths module

Comment: `{{#if (eq item items.lastObject)}}(last){{/if}}`

Comment: @Gaurav Of course. That's a much better solution. Do you like to add it as a separate answer or should I include it in my answer?

Comment: can add that to your answer

Comment: @Gaurav's solution is only reliable if there are NO DUPLICATE objects in your list.